# Error 1049: Unknown database '–-single-transaction'

Tags: mysql

I can't seem to get `mysqldump` to accept the `--single-transaction` flag when I pass it as an option.

If I run this:

```
mysqldump -u root –-single-transaction --databases test > /dev/null
```

Or this:

```
mysqldump -u root –-single-transaction test > /dev/null
```

Then I get the message:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1049: Unknown database '–-single-transaction' when selecting the database
```

I'm using version 5.6:

```
mysqldump --version
mysqldump  Ver 10.13 Distrib 5.6.24, for Linux (x86_64)
```

What's going wrong here?

Comment: What is the name of your Database ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look VERY closely:

```
mysqldump -u root –-single-transaction test 
                  ^--this is not a dash
```

It's some wonky unicode char (ndash, maybe?), which means it's treated as a DB name, **NOT** a command line option.

Comment: _face palm_ Thanks for spotting that. That will (probably) teach me not to copy and paste from solutions on the web.

Comment: Yes, this is an ndash, HTML: `&#8211;`, this [link](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) could help too :P Got to be said, I congratulate Marc B on this, very good catch!

Comment: @SamSwift웃: I'm surprised. normally I'm not quite this awake on a monday morning, but the first dash did look different than the other one, ever so slightly...

Comment: @MarcB, I thought the same thing but instead overlooked it, you have most possibly saved many-a-dev a few hours here! Beside, don't know what you mean morning, Iv'e been at work for hours now!

Comment: Thankfully I copied and pasted exactly what was on the command line! I got that bit right at least. Thanks guys - a great spot regardless of your timezone.